# Analyze stack with IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython, buffer-overflow, stack

In Ida pseudo-code when I press at stack's variable I can see the place of this variable in stack.

```
char buffer[XXX]; // [sp+YYh]
```

How can I get that information (buffer size and place of this buffer in stack)  in IDAPython?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using idapython - using `ida_hexrays` api:

```
ida_hexrays.init_hexrays_plugin()
for var in ida_hexrays.decompile(ea).get_lvars():
    # offset
    offset = -stack_size + var.get_stkoff()
    # variable size
    size = var.width
    # variable type
    type = var.tif
```

And in ida gui, you can see the comments beside declarations.

[image]

Comment: thank you!  1)`stack_size`  is not define, and `var.get_stkoff()` gave me the offset from `rsp` why did I need `stack_size` ?   2)How can I see all the xref of this variable ?

Comment: 1) in my case, i wanted an offset wrt to rbp, thus I used stack size (`idc.get_func_attr(ea, idc.FUNCATTR_FRSIZE)`) to calculate the offset. 2) i'd map these offsets with the variables collected using `get_local_vars(ea, stack_size)` and get their xrefs, as I am not aware of any way of getting xrefs using decompiler interface

Comment: thank you a lot , 1)I didn't find out how can I `use get_local_vars`  I have tried `get_local_vars(0xaaaa,idc.get_func_attr(0xaaaa, idc.FUNCATTR_FRSIZE))` but I got error  `expected 3 arguments, got 2)` and when I looking at `help(get_local_vars)` I see `get_local_vars(prov , ea, out) -> bool`, can you please show me an example?    (2) is `get_local_vars` is better than `ida_hexrays.decompile(ea).get_lvars()` if I only want to get the stack struct ? what is the diffrence?

Comment: hello, can u please ask a separate question with an example of what u would like to do? (as this seems independent or unrelated from your original question and their it'd be easier for someone to answer and you may get a quicker reply). 1) can u show an example code? 2) ida_hexrays uses decompiler interface and algorithm to infer types, and the former is without decompiler